# Can't change string given to function

Tags: c, string, function

Once again, I have stumbled across another unexpected occurrence.

In the following code, it seems that if I use `changeStr()` to change a string, from the function's perspective it has changed, but it has not changed from the program's perspective.

However if I don't use `changeStr()` and set the string myself, it seems to work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* set string to newStr */
void changeStr(char *string, char *newStr) {
    string = realloc(string, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    memcpy(string, newStr, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    printf("String from function=%s\n", string);
}

int main() {
    char *str = NULL;
    changeStr(str, "Hello world!");
    printf("String=%s\n", str);

    /* set string without function */
    char *test = NULL;
    char *newStr = "hello world";
    test = realloc(test, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    memcpy(test, newStr, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    printf("NewStr=%s\n", test);

    free(str);
    free(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String from function=Hello world!
String=(null)
NewStr=hello world
```

I know that function parameters in C are duplicated into a new variable for the function, but only the *pointer* is duplicated - not the *string* itself - so what's going on here?

P.S. I am no multi-year experienced programmer, so not sure if something is wrong.

Comment: Changing `string` in the function won't change `str` in main.  When you "do it yourself", you are directly changing `test`.

Comment: OT: "_from the function's perspective_" vs. "_from the program's perspective._" ... The function IS part of the program... You are referring to `changeStr()` vs. `main()`... It is important to learn to describe problems accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `realloc()` call as you are using it creates a new object and returns the pointer to it, which gets assigned into the `string` local variable in `changeStr()`.

If you want the caller function (`main()`) to have access to that newly allocated object, then the callee function (`changeStr()`) needs to pass the new pointer back to the caller (e.g. as a return value). For example:

```c
char *changeStr(char *string, char *newStr) {
    string = realloc(string, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    memcpy(string, newStr, strlen(newStr) + 1);
    printf("String from function=%s\n", string);
    return string;  // <-- return the updated string object to caller
}

int main() {
    char *str = NULL;
    str = changeStr(str, "Hello world!");
    printf("String=%s\n", str);
```